# Artifactory: copy artifacts to new instance

Tags: artifactory

I have an Artifactory instance running an old version of the community software(not pro) that is about to tear down. We experienced lots of index corruption and crashes recently and I'm very concerned about a fatal crash. There's is a lot of artifacts in it and some very precious ones for our business.

I wish to import artifacts from that old instance to a fresh install running the latest version.

I want to know:

- what is the best path?
- is the migration safe, could it trigger instability on the old Arti?
- Is there a way to do a copy/sync will the old Artifactory remains usable?
- is it possible to filter out artifacts that I don't want to copy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to [export](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF2X/Importing+and+Exporting) the artifacts (and, probably, the configuration as well) from the old instance and [import](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Importing+and+Exporting) them into a new one.

If you have consistency issues, that might affect the export.
I would suggest backing up Artifactory (by creating system export), [running consistency fix and reindexing](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF2X/Dealing+with+Broken+Index) and then export again, upgrade and import.

Good news - on the new version you never will have to reindex or run consistency fix :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, any chance I could clean my export or I should export and import as is and cleanup on the new install?

Comment: Of course, export is a directory tree with all the artifacts inside. you can clean it up in the way you like.

Comment: Just tried the Consistency Fix and artifactory crashed after a while. It had only 1gb of memory allowed. I will retry with 2.

Comment: @JBaruch, I am unable to access the links to export/import/running consistency fix and reindexing - I am prompted for a user name and pwd.  I am interested in the link for "running consistency fix and reindexing".  Can you point me to that link?

Comment: @IvoryMicky Wow, mate, that's an old thread. All that consistency fixes and reindexing stuff is relevant to Artifactory 2 only (we are at 5.0 ATM). Are you sure you need that?

Comment: @JBaruch,I have quite an older version of Artifactory pro 3.0.3.  I am a little nervous about doing this upgrade since it was attempted in the past by someone else and it did not go well - unfortunately I don't have the details about what happened.  I want to basically do the same thing as vinni_f.  Install the latest version freshly on a new vm and then import the artifacts from the old artifactory instance to the newly installed one.  There is about 3T of artifacts that need to be ported over.  What would be the best way to go about it?

Comment: The safest way is full system export from the old one, and full system import to the new one. Should work just fine.